# compile json html-string live with handlebars

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js, handlebars.js

I would like to have a "blog" page with stories, it's not a full blog. I've got my model in Rails containing a title and a body.
In the blog page I get the various posts via a ajax request, and i thought I would be able to compile the result of the body live with Ember.Handlebars.compile.

```
App.BlogPostView = Ember.View.extend({
  template: Ember.Handlebars.compile('<h1>{{title}}</h1>{{body}}')
});
```

It works well up to a certain extend, as I would like to have the tags that are in the body part also compiled. The output I get however is:

## First post

```
<p>first paragraph</p>
```

## Second post

```
<p class="lead">another post with tags</p>
```

The tags that are directly in the `compile` are converted into the expected html tags but the rest is taken literally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution is to use {{{body}}} instead of {{body}}

Comment: Great. Now please chose your answer as selected. :-)